# ASP.NET MVC: Errors when tryig to build a new MembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, membership-provider

I am trying to follow Steve Sandersons MVC2 book and in Chapter 17 he implements a simple / custom MembershipProvider.

However when I "build" my project I get a HUGE array of "...does not implement inherited abstract member..."

Can anyone tell me how I state I dont want to currently implement all of these?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement all of the abstract members of the MembershipProvider base class, even if you only need to use a couple of them for your provider.  You can put filler code in the bodies of the other methods or you can use this:

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

Comment: cool, is there a "quick" way to add all methods or do I have to type all manually?

thanks Paul

Comment: left click on the base class in your code and then hover your mouse over it.  It will give you an option to automatically implement all the abstract methods with `NotImplementedException`

Comment: @KallDrexx - awesome, thanks, now all compiles :)

Next, I was wonder if someone can answer my next question...

Note I have created a manual "List" of Profiles to validate against, how can I make this validate against my "Profiles" table in SQLServer?

Thanks Paul

Comment: @Paul I'd suggest posting a separate question for validating against the Profiles table.  Just as general guidance, however, I'd look into LINQ to SQL for your database access.  There's tons of tutorials out there and it's quick and easy to get up to speed on.  There's also Entity Framework, but it's a more full-featured ERM and I'm assuming more than what you need at this point.

Comment: thanks, new question opened here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425283/help-implementing-simple-custom-membershipprovider

Answer (score 4):

You can implement an empty method, or just use the default implementation in base classes.