# Help implementing simple / custom MembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, membership-provider, code-first, ef-code-first

I have been follow Steve Sandersons MVC2 book and have implemented a simple / custom MembershipProvider. You will not that a valid user has been hardcoded. My question is how do I get this to validate against my "Profiles" SQLServer table?

PS - I am using EF 4.1 Code First

Please see below:

```
public class Profile
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class SimpleMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    private static List<Profile> Members = new List<Profile>
    {
        new Profile { UserId = 1, UserName = "admin", Password = "qwerty123" }
    };

    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        return Members.Exists(m => (m.UserName == username) && (m.Password == password));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your User security data tables. Here's 2 tables for start:

UserNames table:

```
UserID    UserName
1         alex
2         john
```

UserSecurityDetails table:

```
UserID    Password
1         qwerty123
2         password1
```

You then want to make your models (making a UserObjectContext) around those tables. There should be an association between the userIDs.

Then you can use those models in you validate method. Something like:

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
    using(var context = new UserObjectContext())
    {
        return context.UserNames.Any(u => u.UserName == username && u.UserSecurityDetails.Password == password);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, ty for your reply.

So I "need" two tables? No way I can use my existing "Profiles" table that I describe in my "public class Profile"?

Thanks Paul

Comment: No. I'd do it with two tables but it'd work with one just the same. You'll find when you model your data though the Profile entity will be auto-generated so you don't really need to have written that class.

Comment: Okay, cool thanks. I don't suppose you have any web links that will aid me a little further do you?

Thanks Paul

Comment: here is a good guide to using MVC and EF together http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/ or if you liked reading steve sandersons MVC book, you'd probably like Entity Framework 4 recipes